# Visual understanding of $\frac{\mathbb R} {\mathbb Q} $

Tags: real-numbers, intuition, visualization, quotient-set

Consider the quotient set $\frac{\mathbb R} {\mathbb Q} $ obtained by the equivalence relation $$ x \equiv y \mod \mathbb Q \quad \text{iff} \quad x-y \in \mathbb Q  $$
I was wondering if there exists a way to get a visual intuition of it.
I mean, $\frac{\mathbb R} {\mathbb Z} $ can be thought of as the interval $[0,1) $.
To this extent, what does $\frac{\mathbb R} {\mathbb Q} $ look like?
And $\frac{\mathbb [0,1] } {\mathbb Q} $ (if defined in the same way)?

I know the example I provided is a bit different from what I asked, and there may not be an "obvious" or simple answer. I don't have any problem with the "abstract" definition, I was looking for a more "tangible" way to understand it.
Thank you for your help, sorry if my answer seems useless or silly.

Comment: Not sure if there is a better way to visualize it than simply considering one representant per equivalence class. I imagine taking just some real numbers, which are in distinct class (for example I can take $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$, but if I take them, I don't take $1.42$ or $\sqrt{2}-4.76$), and such that all the classes are represented. Of course this visualization is rather bad, because it forgets a little bit the topological group structure.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Completing that representation also requires a modicum of Choice.

Comment: @Arthur Indeed, thanks for the precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to represent $\mathbb R / \mathbb Q$ would be using the axiom of choice to pick up one element per class and to obtain a subset $A$ of the reals.

This is possible. Unfortunately, $A$ has a « bad behavior »! In particular $A \cap [0,1]$ is not Lebesgue measurable. See [here](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/non-measurable-set/) for a proof.

So, representing $A$, for example graphically on the real line is not a simple mission...